# How do not miss the first two lines of a file after using sed and awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following script:

```
file="home/report.csv"

while IFS= read -r line
do
sed 's/\,/;/' > tmp.txt
done <"$file"

file2="home/tmp.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do
awk -F. '{print $1";service" > "report_v2.csv"}' OFS=;
done <"$file2"
```

After the first "While", the file "*tmp.txt*" does not have the first line of "*report.csv*". Then, after the second "While", the file *report_v2.csv* does not have the first line of *tmp.txt*.

Hence, the last file has two lines less than the original one.

This is an example of my files:

***report.csv***

```
1,foo
2,pippo
3,pluto
4,davis
```

***tmp.txt***

```
2;pippo
3;pluto
4;davis
```

***report_v2.csv***

```
3;pluto;service
4;davis;service
```

I need to keep the first two lines of the original file also in the last file. How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `> tmp.txt` with `>> tmp.txt`.

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk and you shouldn't use shell loops just to manipulate text, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). The script you posted wouldn't do anything but hang waiting for input since you aren't giving the sed or awk commands a file to operate on. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do and then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site, Erasmo. You could simplify a good deal with:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="report.csv"
sed 's/\,/;/g' "$file" > tmp.txt
file2="tmp.txt"
awk '{print $1";service"}' "$file2" > report_v2.csv
```

Which should have `tmp.txt` yield:

```
1;foo
2;pippo
3;pluto
4;davis
```

And should have `report_v2.csv` yield:

```
1;foo;service
2;pippo;service
3;pluto;service
4;davis;service
```

Comment: thank you! it works fine!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer as a solution if this is working for you.

Comment: I've already tried to accept your answer but I get the following pop-up message: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: Oh. That sounds like you're trying to upvote the solution rather than click the greyed out checkmark. Either way, glad the solution is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use below command to get the required result

```
awk '{gsub(",",";",$0);print $0";service"}' report.csv >> report_v2.csv
```

output

```
1;foo;service
2;pippo;service
3;pluto;service
4;davis;service
```